# Generating unique links that users can respond to

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, web

I'm building a web app that sends a person an email every time the person is handed a document (a physical piece of paper). The email contains a link that allows the user to request for a document pick up. The link should contain the user's id and the document's id. Is there a safe way to generate this link? Is this a good practice or are there other ways to implement such a thing?

I was thinking of using a hashing algorithm on the link, is this a good approach?

I'm using expressjs for my server side.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for example [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) to create a UUID and pass it on the link, then store on the database to which document the UUID is linked to.

This solves several problems:

- an attacker cannot guess UUIDs
- there is no information on the UUID that can be extracted

I don't think hashing would help in this case, as we just need a way to create a one time token that cannot be guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing, obviously, will not include the document and the user's ID. So it's a bit confusing whether you want secure obfuscation (in which case you would want to use a hash algorithm (salt it if you're paranoid) that then quickly checks whether there is a document with the same ID and generates a new one to avoid document-ID mismatch) or that user and document IDs be included (in which case creating a format that includes both and a brief, usually session-dependent, ID to prevent document-ID mismatch will be just perfect).